# Resources for digitizing in webmap and export?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, software-recommendations, digitizing

Its possible with Google Map API to draw geometries and points. And exporting as well I assume. Is there other alternatives, probably based on Java that can do the same job? I've been researching on this, but without luck. I've read about geotools, wmts-service and more, but nothing close. Another solution could be a light version of QGIS as web interface with limited functions, but that's a major project to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Leaflet plugin called Leaflet Draw

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

You would have to write some code to export the drawing to a data file, ie. GeoJSON, that the user would download...